# Type hinting arbitrary variables for Numba

Tags: python, numpy, type-inference, jit, numba

I am working on a supervised Kmeans algorithm(some of the centroids are fixed, never move, other behave as normal) and I am trying to use Numba to speed things up.

Since Numbas support for comprehensions is shaky at best, basically nonexistent at worst, I reverted to using plain old for loops and hoping that Numba does the job of speeding things up.

My code looks like this:

```
# This function works as intended.
@jit(nopython = True)
def distsqr(p1: Point, p2: Point) -> Numeric:
    """
    Euclidean distance squared between 2 points in R^3.
    """
    return ((p1 - p2) ** 2).sum()


@jit(nopython = True)
def kpp_init(points: PointArray, k: int, fixed_centroids: PointArray) -> PointList:
    """
    The KMeans++ initialization method using some given fixed centroids.
    """
    mobile_centroids = []
    all_centroids    = list(fixed_centroids)
    points_left      = list(points)

    if not len(all_centroids):
            new_centroid = numpy.random.choice(array(list(range(len(points_left)))))

            all_centroids    += [points_left[new_centroid]]
            mobile_centroids += [points_left[new_centroid]]

            del points_left[new_centroid]

    while len(all_centroids) < k:

            # For each point, distance to the nearest centroid, squared.
            # dxsqr = [min(distsqr(centroid, point) for centroid in all_centroids) for point in points_left]
            dxsqr = []
            for point in points_left:
                    dist = []
                    for centroid in all_centroids:
                            dist += [distsqr(point, centroid)]
                    dxsqr += [min(dist)]

            dxsqr_sum = numpy.sum(dxsqr)

            # Not working. Numba wants loops.
            # weights = [dxsqr_val / dxsqr_sum for dxsqr_val in dxsqr]
            weights = []
            for dxsqr_val in dxsqr:
                    weights += [dxsqr_val / dxsqr_sum]

            new_centroid = numpy.random.choice(array(list(range(len(points_left)))), p = weights)

            all_centroids    += [points_left[new_centroid]]
            mobile_centroids += [points_left[new_centroid]]

            del points_left[new_centroid]

            break
    return mobile_centroids
```

Now whenever I try to test this numba gives me a somewhat less scary error:

```
File "E:\Tools\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\typeinfer.py", line 888, in check_var
raise TypingError("Can't infer type of variable '%s': %s" % (var, tp))

numba.errors.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Can't infer type of variable 'dist': list(undefined)
```

This is a pretty easy to understand error, however I have no idea how to solve it. 
So my question is if there's some kind of mechanism to give numba the type of `dist`? Its only ever gonna contain distances so i guess the type would be `list(float32)`. And if there is no such thing how can I get numba to play nice and compile my function?

P.S. The other type annotations are basically all `numpy.ndarray` in one form or another and I doubt they have any effect at all, I put them there for myself, but just in case it matters:

```
Numeric      = Union[numpy.array, numpy.dtype, int, float]      # Numeric

NumericArray = numpy.ndarray                                    # List[Numeric]

Point        = NumericArray                                     # Array[Numeric, Numeric, Numeric]
PointArray   = NumericArray                                     # List[Point]
PointList    = List[Point]
```

Comment: I think your fundamental problem here is that numba only supports lists of primitive types, not lists of arrays.

Comment: @chrisb i found some things hinting at the same answer but... that would mean that a HUGE part of problems/algorithms are not compatible with numba at a fundamental level

Comment: Yes & no... arrays can get you pretty far.  Without deeply studying your code, it is fairly clear that some of the uses of lists are unnecessary and would be more efficient with an array anyways (e.g. `dxsqr` and `weights`)

Comment: @chrisb yes but the fundamental problem is that the algorithms I work with use points in n-dimensional space. So to represent a point, I need an n-tuple. 2-dimensional arrays might do it instead of lists of tuples/arrays to represents collections of such points, but since numpy arrays are immutable and every append creates a whole new array I dont know how optimal that would be.

Comment: Using arrays will be much faster compared to lists. You already know the amount of points and centroids right from the start. So you can pre-allocate all memory needed, that will always be faster.

Comment: @RutgerKassies Yes, you are right, however the clusters of points always change. At each iteration the centroids are recomputed and the clusters need to be recomputed too and the number of points in each cluster changes. That means that in the `clusterize` function I need to use some data structure that can support lots of appends since clusterization is basically creating a new list/array/etc. for each centroid and then iterating trough the points and appending each point to the cluster of the centroid nearest to it. So an optimal append is kinda necessary here.

Comment: And Im not sure if numpy arrays that get reallocated at every append are the best choice(or are they? does numba somehow optimize the appends to arrays so much that they become worth it?)

Comment: Do you have some reference with a description of your algorithm? You shouldn't append to a Numpy array if you want performance, but the same holds true for lists. Normal kmeans can certainly be done in Numba by declaring the data structures upfront. Using your example, you know that each point will always be assigned to a single cluster, so you can use a 1D array of `len(points)` to store the assignment for each point. That doesn't need appending or a list, and will be much faster.

Comment: @RutgerKassies My algorithm is the default KMeans one, it can be trivially found on sites like wikipedia.